# ¿Como Desplegar Menu al hacer click derecho en un DataGridView C#?

Tags: c#, datagrid

**explico lo que necesito:** Quiero que, al hacer Click derecho sobre **una celda** de un `DataGridView` que se me desplegué un menú sobre él(sobre la celda).

**El problemas es:** Que al hacer click derecho el menú siempre se me desplega en la parte superior del `DataGridView` y **NO** en la celda clickeada.

**Imagen del error.**[image: Error al hacer click derecho]

Hice click derecho donde esta el punto rojo pero de todas formas el menu aparece por el sector superior del `DataGridView`, y asi en cualesquier lugar que hace click derecho.

**Hora de mostrar codigo:** El siguiente codigo es la funcion que tengo hasta ahora.

```
    private void lista_dias_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
            int posiscion = lista_dias.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
            // if (posiscion >= 0) {
            menu.Items.Add("agregar").Name = "AGREGAR";
            menu.Items.Add("eliminar").Name = "Eliminar";
            menu.Items.Add("detalles").Name = "DETALLES";
            //}
            menu.Show(lista_dias, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
    }
```

Dicho evento fue Creado automáticamente desde la interfaces que tiene C#, el evento es `CellMouseClick`.

Por adelantado gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Creo que tu evento es [este](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Pues no ya que `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` no es un evento de Mouse

Comment: `menu.Show(dataGridView1.PointToScreen(e.Location));` ¿No funciona?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se me ocurre que puedes hacerlo obteniendo la coordenada de cada celda.

> Aquí Puedes obtener mas información sobre el [Método DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getcelldisplayrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Asumiendo que tu `DataGridView` se llama : **lista_dias**:

```
private void lista_dias_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {

       lista_dias.CurrentCell = lista_dias.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

       ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
       menu.Items.Add("agregar").Name = "AGREGAR";
       menu.Items.Add("eliminar").Name = "Eliminar";
       menu.Items.Add("detalles").Name = "DETALLES";


       //Obtienes las coordenadas de la celda seleccionada. 
       Rectangle coordenada = lista_dias.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);

       int anchoCelda = coordenada.Location.X; //Ancho de la localizacion de la celda
       int altoCelda = coordenada.Location.Y;  //Alto de la localizacion de la celda

       //Y para mostrar el menú lo haces de esta forma:  
       int X = anchoCelda + lista_dias.Location.X;
       int Y = altoCelda + lista_dias.Location.Y + 15;

       menu.Show(lista_dias, new Point(X, Y));
    }
}
```

> De esta forma te funciona perfectamente lo que solicitas. Esta linea: `lista_dias.CurrentCell = lista_dias.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];` es para colocar el foco en la  celda que se da el `Click Derecho`. Si no deseas colocar el foco en la celda puedes usar `lista_dias.BeginEdit(true);` en lugar de la otra linea mencionada, esto hará que te muestre el menú en la celda y que celda que contenía el foco antes de dar Click no pierda el foco.

El resultado obtenido es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te ayude... Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

toma esta estructura, a mi me va muy bien.

Explico: Dentro del grid, haces click derecho sobre tu registro, a continuacion se despliega una pestaña, donde te da una opcion, en mi caso, "Eliminar Producto", de inmediato, se elimina el registro seleccionado y a su vez se elimina de la base de datos.

Para info acerca de la tecnologia que aplico: Entity Framework, C# y SQL server.

```
   public int rowIndex { get; set; }


          private void dgvProductos_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                    {
                        this.dgvProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                        this.rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
                        this.dgvProductos.CurrentCell = this.dgvProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
                        this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.dgvProductos, e.Location);
                        contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
                    }
                }

                private void contextMenuStrip1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    ProductosEF _bdVentas = new ProductosEF();

                    if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea eliminar el producto?", "¡Advertencia!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        string _codigo_barra = dgvProductos.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        _bdVentas.DeleteProduct(_codigo_barra);

                    }
                    _bdVentas.SaveChanges();

                    CargarGrid();
                }
```

Espero de alguna u otra manera haber ayudado a solucionar tu rollo o al menos una idea.

Comment: La parte en donde se captura la posición del cursor, muy buena. Eso es más estético y sin cálculos.