# ¿Cómo crear el evento al dar clic en una de las opciones del contextmenustrip en el datagridview?

Tags: c#

De la pregunta: [¿Como Desplegar Menu al hacer click derecho en un DataGridView C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/140627/69447)  me funciono...pero ahora:
¿Cómo crear el evento al hacer clic en una de las opciones del menú?

Espero puedan ayudarme..de antemano te agradezco.. Saludos

Comment: Hola Bienvenido/a a [StackOverFlow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)  Mira [ask] y [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Además deberías realizar el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer esto es muy fácil sigue estos pasos:

1 - Una vez tenga agregado tu `ContextMenuStrip` agrega las opciones que deseas y asigna un nombre a la propiedad `Name` para que puedas identificarlo al momento de dar click.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2 - Con el `ContextMenuStrip` seleccionado, ve a la ventana de `Propiedades` y selecciona el icono del rayo, que corresponde a los eventos, localiza el evento llamado `ItemClicked` da doble click sobre este para que te genere el evento en el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3- En el evento generado puedes controlar la opción del menú que seleccionas de la siguiente manera:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
     switch (e.ClickedItem.Name)
     {
         case "toolStripMenuItem1":
             ///Aquí todo lo que quieras hacer cuando des click en esa opción
             break;
         case "toolStripMenuItem2":
             ///...
             break;
         case "toolStripMenuItem3":
             ///...
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
}
```

> Ten en cuenta que esto: `switch (e.ClickedItem.Name)` también puedes usar la propiedad `Text` si deseas `switch (e.ClickedItem.Text)` y saber los nombres: `toolStripMenuItem1` deben ser los que asignes tú. y Si no quieres usar `switch` podrías hacerlo usando `if(e.ClickedItem.Name) { ...} else {...}`

---

Además puedes ahorrarte el paso número 2, si lo haces directamente desde el código, de esta forma:

```
contextMenuStrip1.ItemClicked += contextMenuStrip1_ItemClicked;
```

> Aquí te estas suscribiendo al evento...

Comment: Te agradezco mucho que te hayas tomado el tiempo para ayudarme de veras saludos...y quiero pedirte nuevamente tu ayuda...soy nuevo en este mundo de programación..mi problema es en 2 partes.¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar una etiqueta o el nombre del boton al poner el mouse sobre el boton? Y ¿Cómo seleccionar todas las columnas de un row en el datagridview?

Comment: Si mi respuesta te ha servido, vota a favor y marca la [respuesta como aceptada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/69447) para que la pregunta quede como concluida. En la pregunta que haces, lo que necesitas es un objeto `ToolTips`, mira [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjJAm3RK4G4) te explica como hacerlo con un `TextBox` y se hace exactamente igual en un botón. No entiendo bien la segunda pregunta de seleccionar las columnas.

Comment: Mi segunda pregunta...en mi tabla de datagrid tengo las columnas Codigo, Nombre, Apellido, Observacion...cuando das clic en un nombre cualquiera solo te selecciona o sea se sombrea el Nombre y no el resto de su informacion

Comment: Marca la flecha hacia arriba en la respuesta para votar a favor. Con respecto a tu pregunta te refieres a que se muestre la fila completa seleccionada  y no solo una celda, para esto en tu `DataGridView` debes buscar la propiedad llamada `SelectionMode` y colocarla como `FullRowSelect`, si quieres puedes hacerlo directamente desde el código, coloca esto en el `Load` del formulario: `dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;`

Comment: Dice q no puedo votar por este comentario

Comment: Igual te agradezco muchisimo

Comment: Por eso ya le di..y me envia una notificacio..."Gracias por tu comentario,

Comment: el video me da la etiqueta en forma de nube de idea...yo solo lo quisiera en un rectangulo simple...como cuando señalas el boton cerrar en una ventana...te dice su nombre